# Mongodb shell alternative

Tags: mongodb

Can I do the operations like adding to shard/cluster not through mongodb shell, but through linux cli?

```
root@mongo-2:/etc/puppet# mongo --host mongo-1 --port 27019
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.10
connecting to: mongo-1:27019/test
> rs.initiate()
{
    "info2" : "no configuration explicitly specified -- making one",
    "me" : "mongo-1:27019",
    "info" : "Config now saved locally.  Should come online in about a minute.",
    "ok" : 1
}
> rs.add('mongo-2:27020'')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do this by using the mongo shell tool:

1. Pass in the commands using the [**`--eval`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongo/#cmdoption--eval) option on the command line so you can do things like this:

   > mongo --host mongo-1 --port 27019 --eval 'rs.initiate(); rs.add("mongo-2:27020")'
2. Or for longer instructions add them to a JavaScript file and call that from the command line:

   > mongo --host mongo-1 --port 27019 commands.js

Generally have a good look at all the command line options in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongo/#bin.mongo), or otherwise employ your programming/scripting language of choice where you can use a mongodb driver in order to provide your automation scripts/utilities that you require.